# PHP: time>time()

Tags: php, time

I have:

```
$lastActivationDelay = time() + 8;
if($lastActivationDelay<$last_activation)
```

right now, not working properly.

What i want to do is if you try to enter the page, and
`if $last_activation is under the $lastactivationdelay time, then echo false, else true`.

So `if eight seconds from now is over $last_activation, then true, if its under, then false`.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's wrong based on the code you've supplied. What is $last_activation being set as?

Comment: What is $last_activation == ?

Comment: Please clarify. Your 3rd and 4th sentences are logical opposites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$last_activation` exists in the past, your comparison is backwards.

`if ($lastActivationDelay > $last_activation) { echo 'too soon';
}`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do:

```
if($last_activation+8 < time())
```